# Prove that in general the set of the right zero divisors is different from the set of left zero divisors in a ring R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove that in general the set of the right zero divisors is different from the set of left zero divisors in ring $R$.

The ring is arbitrary. Does exist general proof for it ? 
Attention that the problem is comparing two sets. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need a "general proof" for an existence statement: you just need to find an example. A universal example is the ring generated by two generators $ab$ satisfying $ab = 0$, whose underlying abelian group is free on words in the generators $a, b$ on words of the form $b^n a^m$. Then $a$ is a left but not right zero divisor, and dually $b$ is a right but not left zero divisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be a countable dimensional vector space over a field, and fix a basis $\{b_1,b_2,\ldots\}$.

Let $A$ be the transformation determined by the rule $A(b_i)=b_{i+1}$. Let $B$ be the transformation determined by $B(b_1)=0$ and $B(b_i)=b_{i-1}$ for $i>1$. Let $C$ be the transformation determined by $C(b_i)=b_1$ for all $i$.

Then $BA=1$ so $B$ is not a right zero divisor. But $BC=0$, so $B$ is a left zero divisor.

Comment: thanks man for this example but you show me that why B is not right zero divisor in other hand " no element does it exist for example D (not zero) that BD=0 ? "

Comment: @farshchian2090 I think you are asking why there can't exist a nonzero $D$ such that $DB=0$ (I already showed $BC=0$ so $C=D$ suffices.) If $DB=0$, then $D=DBA=0$.

Comment: yes you exactly pointed to my mind e.g DB=0 . in this example B is left zero divisor but it has not cleared that B can not be a right divisor . it mean's that is this any nonzero element D such that DB=0 . if we don't have this element in your example then B can't be a right divisor .

Comment: please example such element with above condition thanks a lot !

Comment: @farshchian2090 I do not understand your last comments. In my previous comment, I demonstrated $DB=0$ implies $D=0$, and so $B$ is not a right zero divisor. Since $B$ is a left zero divisor, I have shown the two sets are different from each other.

Comment: Aha your mind is your ring in this example just contains these 3 elements A,B,C ? is this true???

Comment: @farshchian2090 no, not at all, my example is the full ring of transforms.. I needed B alone as an example for you. I needed A and C to prove that B is a left-not-right zero divisor. I suggest you reread everything again because you seem to be misunderstanding a simple argument.

Comment: so see Mr  rschwieb I want to prove that if AB=0 for all transformation A then A=0 . then it is concluded B is not right zero divisor . you brought me one example that is not sufficient for proving being not right zero divisor B . is that true ?

Comment: @farshchian2090 Relabel your A as D, and you have just asked me to show that for all D, DB=0 implies D=0. *That is precisely what I said twice already in my comments above.*

Comment: OK I got it thank you so much. if DB=0 then DBA=0 or D.1=0 and so D=0 yes very good this is exactly what I was trying to find it . thank you.